# Protractor-cucumber: isPresent is not function

Tags: cucumber, protractor

I have my code:

```
this.Then(/^I should see "([^"]*)" link$/, function (callback) {
   var logoutpath = by.xpath('//div[@id="account_logout"]/a');

    browser.wait(function() {
        return dv.isElementPresent(logoutpath);
    }, 30000);

    browser.driver.isElementPresent(logoutpath).then(function(isPresent){
        expect(isPresent.isPresent()).toBe(true); 
        browser.driver.findElement(logoutpath).then(function(start){
            start.click();
        });
    });
    browser.sleep(2222);

    console.log(">>>>>>>"+browser.getTitle());

    callback();
});
```

when i run and get error in console:

```
TypeError: isPresent.isPresent is not a function
at c:\Users\binhlex\WebstormProjects\untitled\Feature\Steps\login_steps.js:33:30
at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runInFrame_ (c:/Users/binhlex/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/../webdriver/promise.js:1857:20)
at [object Object].goog.defineClass.notify (c:/Users/binhlex/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/../webdriver/promise.js:2448:25)
at [object Object].promise.Promise.notify_ (c:/Users/binhlex/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/../webdriver/promise.js:564:12)
at Array.forEach (native)
```

I have some question?
- Why didn't i use `isPresent` method?
- When i run `console.log(">>>>>>>"+browser.getTitle());`, why it display `>>>>>>>Promise::222 {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending"}`, how can i use it to verify with expected title of the page?

Answer (score 1):

To your latest question, because browser.getTitle() is a promise, if you want to console.log Title you'd have to do: `browser.getTitle().then(function(title){console.log(title)});`

For your first question, I don't get why you are trying to obfuscate the code so much. in protractor you don't have to wait for element before clicking it. ( if you don't have ignore synchronization on).

So this:

```
browser.driver.findElement(logoutpath).then(function(start){
            start.click();
```

equeals:

```
logoutpath.click()
```

Comment: Thank for your response, about question `isPresent.isPresent is not a function` function, i want to check element `logout` is present on page or not. So do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I'd use expected conditions: https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions

    `var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;`


    `// Waits for the element with id 'account_logout' to be visible on the dom.`

    `browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf($('#account_logout')), 5000);`